# Testing an association with an alias_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, alias

I'm planning on using alias attributes for several of my model associations. **Note:** I'm completely aware that I can also *alias* this association via:

```
belongs_to :type, class_name: "AlbumType"
```

but would like to further explore the [alias_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-alias_attribute) method. With this in mind I have an `Album` that belongs to an `AlbumType`.

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  alias_attribute :type, :album_type
  belongs_to :album_type
end

class AlbumType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :albums
end
```

So far so good. I'd now like to test the aliased association in my album spec. It appears that a traditional `belongs_to` shoulda-matcher isn't clever enough to identify that *type* is an *album_type*, even after specifying the class name. I'm certainly not adverse to writing a traditional RSpec test but not really sure how in this case. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
RSpec.describe Album, type: :model do
  describe "ActiveRecord associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:album_type) }

    context "alias attributes" do
      it { should belong_to(:type).class_name("AlbumType") }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using `alias_attribute` for that purpose. As far as I'm aware, `shoulda` uses `ActiveRecord::Reflection` to investigate associations. The only thing `alias_attribute` does is create methods to proxy messages from the target to the origin through getter, setter and '?' methods. It was clearly intended to work with ActiveRecord attributes and not general purpose methods.

The effect of that is that `alias_attribute` won't register those targets as ActiveRecord associations and the current implementation of `shoulda` won't be able to catch them.

There are also side effects to that pattern. As you might know, when you create an association, ActiveRecord also creates helper methods to make your life easier. For instance, a `belongs_to` also creates:

```
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```

By your example, using `alias_attribute` won't give you `album.build_album_type` and that's something other contributors may be willing to rely upon, as they expect that to be the default behavior.

The best way to handle this is precisely what you told you wouldn't like to do, using the `belongs_to` method to create the association under the name you really want.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. Currently in the process of setting up my ActiveModel serializers so this came in the nick of time.